# оптимизация текста питон

Tags: python, текст

я новичок и я не смог сам найти ответ на этот вопрос.
Сама суть вопроса заключается в том, что я написал крайне простенькую программу на ткинтере и хотел добавить в нее лицензию дждипиэл, проблема в том что программа не понимает если в нее просто вставить текст, ведь там довольно часто все пишется с новой строки а в питоне это обозначается \n .
Если не затруднит, то напишите программу, которая принимает текст и выдает уже готовый, где поставлены \n вместо написания новой строки

Comment: Тут не пишут программы, тут помогают тем, кто сам пишет и столкнулся с проблемой. С таким запросом - лучше на фриланс. Если сами напишете, то это тема "Работа со строками". Она легкая. Команда ввода: input ().

Comment: скорее всего Вам нужен синтаксис heredoc - https://lofic.github.io/tips/python-heredoc.html

Comment: но как тогда решить проблему? хоть намек, я знаю как разделять текст по определенным символам и заменить их, но как мне указать написание с новой строки как разделитель?

Comment: новая строка и есть символо ``\n``. Непонятно в чем проблема и что вам нужно. Разберитесь сначала с этим, а то простое вставление \n в текст, вам не только не поможет, но и приведет текст в малочитаемый вид.

Comment: ну так мне нужно чтобы программа выводила текст правильно, когда я просто вставляю туда большой текст оно не работает, либо отображает не корректдно, ведь оно не понимает простого написания с новой строки, поэтому приходится ставить там \n где начинается новая строка, но я хочу это оптимизировать

Comment: Вы пробовали то, что я написал?

Comment: я искал информацию но пока мои скилы не смогли через хередок решить проблему, я еще час булу разбираться, но всеравно попробую, если смогу завтра отпившусь об успехе

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `"""лицензия на много строк"""` (три кавычки)

Comment: программ, которые заменяют любой символ на что угодно, уже написано примерно 100500. Называются общим словом - текстовый редактор. В любом есть функция "найти и заменить."

Comment: Стас, дякую,как я мог о трех кавычках забыть

Comment: теперь появилась другая проблема, текст не проматывается ;)   поищу решения на просторах форума

Answer (score 0):

"""лицензия на много строк"""

Answer (score 0):

код сделать будет сложно и возможно у он будет работать с перебоями так что проще всего юзать тройные кавычки. пример:
"""Hello
World
and
others"""
ошибок быть не может!